# How secure is RSA for authentication?

Tags: rsa, passwords

I'm building a web-based password manager system and would ideally not send sufficient information to the servers to decode the raw text passwords of users. The plan is to encrypt the raw text passwords of users using AES-256 with a master password only known to the user.

In order to authenticate the users, I was considering an asymmetric algorithm as I do not want to send the master password of the user to the servers. I was thinking of using RSA in order to create a public key using the master password as the private key, and store it on the server-side. When authenticating, the plan is to generate and encrypt a session key using the public key on the server-side and then send it to the client where it could be decrypted only by the private key. Can you see any security flaws in this system? Are there any other algorithms you'd suggest for such authentication?

Comment: You might want to replace "the master password _is_ the private key" with "the master password (and data from the server) are the _base_ to generating the private key". Because right now the server could detect re-used master passwords across users by simply looking for equal public keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few flaws and uncertainties:

- First of all, this is a web based manager; that means, what ever technology is used, the user needs to trust the server; if the code delivered by the server changes it would be very easy to send back the plain password. For this reason JavaScript based security solutions are generally frowned upon.
- If you need to trust the server you may as well just rely on TLS (which you should be using whatever the cost, the server certificate is one of the few ways that trust can be obtained.
- A password is not a private key. An RSA private key is generated through key pair generation, which relies on obtaining two primes, starting with a random source of data. Although you can use the password to seed this generation there are still problems if the key pair generation somehow differs then the scheme fails. Also, in JavaScript or browsers, the RSA key pair generation will probably take a long time and RSA key pair generation may take longer for some passwords as the key pair generation time (or the time to find "random" primes, to be precise) is indeterministic.

ECC key pair generation for similar strength key pairs is much easier, by the way. RSA private keys can also be encrypted using Password Based Encryption, but that will require some kind of storage (e.g. your server?).

Not so helpful maybe but this question comes up now and then. I won't give any specific hints besides the ones I already gave you. I highly recommend studying the ones already out there first; many have their protocols written down in white papers, blog articles, FAQ's etc. if you look hard enough.